# Handle Different Cases Using Drop-In UI

Tags: braintree

I am trying to use the Braintree Drop-In UI with a subscription service on my website. How do I tell my server how to create the subscription?

For Instance:

A user already has a payment method in the vault so when they hit submit my server just uses the payment nonce given to create the subscription since they used a vaulted method.

BUT, what if a user adds a new payment method? How does my server know to create a new payment method for them since it is not vaulted and I cannot just use the nonce to make a new subscription?

Really what I need to know is how can my server know the user is adding a new method versus using one already vaulted in the Drop-In UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).

To create a subscription using an existing payment method, first generate a `client_token`, passing in a [`customer_id`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/ruby#customer_id).

```
@client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(
  :customer_id => a_customer_id
)
```

After passing this `client_token` into your Drop-in UI, the customer's previous payment methods will be within the form. The customer can then select one of these payment methods, or create a new one, and the new one will be selected.

After form submission, a `payment_method_nonce` that corresponds to the selected payment_method will be sent to your server. You can then call [`Subscription.create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby), passing in the `payment_method_nonce`. See our [`payment_method_nonce`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby#payment_method_nonce) documentation for more information.

```
result = Braintree::Subscription.create(
  :payment_method_nonce => "payment_method_nonce",
  :plan_id => "silver_plan"
)
```